# Overwrite issue in ruby Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

[below is my code, it only print out 1 records rather than all records in the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jry7f.png)

```
file.xpath("//record").each do |node|
  $records << {
  "id" => node.xpath('id').text, 
  "first_name" => node.xpath('first_name').text, 
  "last_name" => node.xpath('last_name').text, 
  "email" => node.xpath('email').text, 
  "gender" => node.xpath('gender').text, 
  "ip_address" => node.xpath('ip_address').text,
  "send_date" => node.xpath('send_date').text,
  "email_body" => node.xpath('email_body').text,
  "email_title" => node.xpath('email_title').text
}
puts $records
end
```

[this is the xml file for records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH9B5.png)

```
<record>
<id>1</id>
<first_name>Adiana</first_name>
<last_name>Paulat</last_name>
<email>apaulat0@technorati.com</email>
<gender>Female</gender>
<ip_address>216.250.245.57</ip_address>
<send_date>2017-05-17T23:04:27Z</send_date>
<email_body>​</email_body>
<email_title>Up-sized</email_title>
</record>
<record>
<id>2</id>
<first_name>Jaye</first_name>
<last_name>O'Donnelly</last_name>
<email>jodonnelly1@amazon.com</email>
<gender>Male</gender>
<ip_address>15.66.35.144</ip_address>
<send_date>2017-11-09T05:08:56Z</send_date>
<email_body><script>alert('hi')</script></email_body>
<email_title>real-time</email_title>
</record>
```

[this is the output of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u2Qz.png)

```
{"id"=>"1", "first_name"=>"Adiana", "last_name"=>"Paulat", "email"=>"apaulat0@technorati.com", "gender"=>"Female", "ip_address"=>"216.250.245.57", "send_date"=>"2017-05-17T23:04:27Z", "email_body"=>"​", "email_title"=>"Up-sized"}
```

I asked my tutor and he said that I had overwrite issue in my line and I couldnt find it. Anyone can help?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Try pasting the code itself, its more readable and easier than an image

Comment: @subash edited, thank you for letting me know

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do, do you just want to print the data or do you need to store that data in a variable and send it somewhere for processing?

Comment: @Subash extract the data from xml file and output the data

Answer (score 1):

When I write your XML into a file called `yo.xml`, and run this little program...

```
require 'nokogiri'
file = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('yo.xml').read())
p file.xpath('//record').size
```

...I get `1`. One record.

This is probably because your XML has no single top-level node, so Nokogiri assumed when it found the first `</record>` that the XML ended there.

When I wrap your content with `<records>...</records>`, I get `2`.

Comment: thanks @phlip for the answer but im unable to change the xml file to a single root as this is a part of requirement

Comment: Can you parse with `Nokogiri::XML('<records>' + File.open('yo.xml').read() + '</records>')`? But the answer with `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml)` should be the winning solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because you have 2 root nodes in your xml document, which isn't allowed and isn't liked (nokogiri appears to parse the first one then stop). What you have isn't an xml document, it's an xml fragment, but nokogiri does let you work with those as well, you just need to initialize the file as:

```
file = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml)
```

and then you can iterate both of the `record` elements using the xpath:

```
file.xpath("./record").each do |node|
```

I'm not the greatest at xpath, this seems to be working though, I'm not sure why `//record` doesn't work when you use a fragment while this does.

Comment: I did change my code to your suggestion but i didnt get any output from the program



file.xpath("//record").each do |node|
    $records << {
    "id" => node.xpath('id').text, 
    "first_name" => node.xpath('first_name').text, 
    "last_name" => node.xpath('last_name').text, 
    "email" => node.xpath('email').text, 
    "gender" => node.xpath('gender').text, 
    "ip_address" => node.xpath('ip_address').text,
    "send_date" => node.xpath('send_date').text,
    "email_body" => node.xpath('email_body').text,
    "email_title" => node.xpath('email_title').text
    }
    end

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the incoming data then you can use this to get exactly what you are looking for

```
Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml_string).search('record').each {|record| p Hash.from_xml(record.to_xml)}
```